# What is the correct node js version for installing mobile first development kit and migration assistance

Tags: node.js, npm, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mobilefirst-windows

I have mobile first server version:  8.0.0.00-20180220-083852

From there I downloaded the cli and migration assistance tool, however, I always get this error:

npm ERR! node v6.9.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     G:\mobile\nodejs\npm-debug.log

I did a searched on stackoverflow, however, all the suggestion is to use the correct nodejs and npm version. I believed I have used the correct one.

Any ideas? By the way, I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Minimum supported node.js version is 4.2.3. Also, with the fast evolving node and npm packages, the MobileFirst CLI might not be fully functional with all the available versions of node and npm including the latest versions. Ensure that node is on version 6.11.1 and npm version is 3.10.10, for proper functioning of the CLI.

For more details see here : [Prerequisites](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/using-mobilefirst-cli-to-manage-mobilefirst-artifacts/#prerequisites)

Comment: Ran "npm install -g --no-optional mfpdev-cli", successfully with Node 6.11.3 and npm 3.10.10. However, I still got the error while running "npm install -g --no-optional mfpmigrate-cli". It is the same error.

Comment: Is it same error ? does error reflect v6.11.1 or v6.9.3  ?
'npm install -g mfpmigrate-cli' worked for me

Comment: The error reflect v.6.11.3 for node and v3.10.10 for npm. It also shows this error message  "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081". I tried to ping that address but it failed. Should we got the ip for that address?

Comment: Can you  set npm regsitry to default n try ?

Comment: It seems to be there is a problem with command 'npm install -g mfpmigrate-cli'.Can you download cli from your devkit server's mfp console download center as explained here :

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/migration-cookbook/#migration-assistance-tool

and install locally 
''npm install -g tgz_filename''

Comment: I tried to use the downloaded file as well. However, I got the same error.  Do you think it is time to open PMR? By the way, I tried to set the npm registry to https://registry.npmjs.org as well.

Comment: Opened PMR on this issue. It seems there is a problem with the existing repository. IBM will fix it. I am able to install it with this command: "npm install -g mfpmigrate-cli@8.0.20170615055734"

Comment: @widj91942 thanks for the update.Can you try with node -v8.11.1 ,npm -v5.6.0 ?. I am able to install latest mfpmigrate-cli(8.0.20171211072611) with above node and npm versions.Always try latest coz latest  includes lot of changes.Let me know I will modify my answer if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, I did try the latest node (node -v8.11.1 and npm 5.6.0) but it failed too.

Comment: This works fine on my  mac machine seems to be problem on only Windows 10 machine

Answer (score 0):

Please try with latest version of MobileFirst Server and also make sure that your system has following node and npm version installed.

- npm version: `3.10.10`
- node version: `v6.11.3`